# Test if File was Modified After Date in File Name

Tags: bash, files, osx, timestamps

I have a files named with `YYYYMMDD` in the file name, such as

```
file-name-20151002.txt
```

I want to determine if *this* file was modified after 2015-10-02.

### Notes:

- I can do this by looking at the output of `ls`, but I know that parsing the output of `ls` is a bad idea.
- I don't need to find *all* files dated after a specific date, just need to test *one* specific file at a time.
- I am not concerned about the file being modified on the same date after I created it. That is, I just want to know if this file with `20151002` in the name was modified on Oct 03, 2015 or later.
- I am on MacOs 10.9.5.

Comment: Apologies for not including the OS earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some possible ways with :

- `OSX stat`:

  ```
  newer () {
  tstamp=${1:${#1}-12:8}
  mtime=$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y%m%d" "$1")
  [[ ${mtime} -le ${tstamp} ]] && printf '%s\n' "$1 : NO: mtime is ${mtime}" || printf '%s\n' "$1 : YES: mtime is ${mtime}"
  }
  ```
- `GNU date`:

  ```
  newer () {
  tstamp=${1:${#1}-12:8}
  mtime=$(date '+%Y%m%d' -r "$1")
  [[ ${mtime} -le ${tstamp} ]] && printf '%s\n' "$1 : NO: mtime is ${mtime}" || printf '%s\n' "$1 : YES: mtime is ${mtime}"
  }
  ```
- `zsh` only:

  ```
  zmodload zsh/stat
  newer () {
  tstamp=${1:${#1}-12:8}
  mtime=$(zstat -F '%Y%m%d' +mtime -- $1)
  [[ ${mtime} -le ${tstamp} ]] && printf '%s\n' "$1 : NO: mtime is ${mtime}" || printf '%s\n' "$1 : YES: mtime is ${mtime}"
  }
  ```

---

Usage:

```
newer FILE
```

Example output:

```
file-name-20150909.txt : YES: mtime is 20151026
```

or

```
file-name-20151126.txt : NO: mtime is 20151026
```

Answer (score 9):

The following script will check the dates of all files specified on the command line:

It requires GNU versions of `sed`, `date`, and `stat`

```
$ cat check-dates.sh 
#! /bin/bash

for f in "$@" ; do
  # get date portion of filename
  fdate=$(basename "$f" .txt | sed -re 's/^.*(2015)/\1/')

  # convert it to seconds since epoch + 1 day
  fsecs=$(echo $(date +%s -d "$fdate") + 86400 | bc )

  # get modified timestamp of file in secs since epoch
  ftimestamp=$(stat -c %Y "$f")

  [ "$ftimestamp" -gt "$fsecs" ] && echo "$f has been modified after $fdate"
done

$ ./check-dates.sh file-name-20151002.txt 
file-name-20151002.txt has been modified after 20151002
$ ls -l file-name-20151002.txt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cas cas 0 Oct 26 19:21 file-name-20151002.txt
```

Here's a version that is untested but should work on Macs (and on FreeBSD etc) if I've read the on-line man pages correctly:

```
#! /bin/bash

for f in "$@" ; do
  # get date portion of filename
  fdate=$(basename "$f" .txt | sed -e 's/^.*\(2015\)/\1/')

  # convert it to seconds since epoch + 1 day
  fsecs=$(echo $(date -j -f %Y%m%d "$fdate" +%s) + 86400 | bc )

  # get modified timestamp of file in secs since epoch
  ftimestamp=$(stat -f %m "$f")

  [ "$ftimestamp" -gt "$fsecs" ] && echo "$f has been modified after $fdate"
done
```

Comment: An even better solution would be one not requiring 4-5 extensions vs POSIX.

Comment: Feel free to write your own version, then.  I write what I want to write, not what you want me to write....and that includes using GNU versions of tools.  IMO, GNU **IS** the de-facto standard.  and the relative numbers of linux distros in use vs non-linux, non-gnu *nixes supports that.

Comment: @cas: a rather harsh reply to Thomas's comment which was, I believe, just a suggestion to improve your solution... In the real world, having "the most standard possible" script is not only a bonus, but is necessary (or rather, mandatory). Many places can't install the GNU version of tools (I happen to know 3 different places where some system's latest vers of bash are 2.x and awk is so old it is very, very close to the original one). This question's needs is probably not "critical" (but could be) and also not often seeked/used by other people, but in general, having a portable solution is a +

Comment: I am getting `sed: illegal option -- r` with MacOS 10.9.5.

Comment: `-r` is a GNU `sed` option to tell it to use extended regular expressions.  You could change the sed script to use basic regexp rather than extended (e.g.`sed -e 's/^.*\(2015\)/\1/')` but the rest of the script will probably still fail because it requires the GNU versions of `date` and `stat`, and I don't think Macs come with them as standard (although they are available for Mac in pre-compiled packages)

Comment: I don't have a Mac available otherwise i'd have a go at rewriting the script to make use of the Mac versions of those tools - Mac versions of standard tools are an odd mix of GNU, freebsd, and Apple-modified versions.

Comment: You are correct. After adjusting the `sed` command as per your comment, I get `date: illegal time format`...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804966/date-command-does-not-follow-linux-specifications-mac-os-x-lion - in particular, the first answer mentions installing GNU `coreutils` (which includes both `date` and `stat`) from the MacPorts archive.  They will be called `gdate` and `gstat`.  The URL in that answer seems broken, obsolete perhaps...the MacPorts home page is at http://www.macports.org/

Comment: AFAICT, the `stat` command in freebsd/apple dialect would be `ftimestamp=$(stat -f %m "$f")`

Comment: And, I'm not 100% sure if it will work, but you could try `date -j -f %Y%m%d "$fdate" +%s`

Comment: Hmmm.. Upon further testing it seems that it always thinks the files are old. I have files:  `a-20151028.txt` dated `Oct 28 23:58`, `b-20151028.txt` dated `Oct 29 00:00` and `c-20151028.txt` dated `Oct 29 00:02` and all three are reported as `old`. Also, as I need output for both old and new I changed the last comparison to `if [ "$ftimestamp" -gt "$fsecs" ]; then echo "new" else echo "old" fi`.

Comment: try adding some print statements after setting $fdate, $fsecs, and $ftimestamp to see what those vars are actually being set to.  sorry, i have no ability to debug scripts using mac versions of commands on my own system (i really should get around to setting up a freebsd vm).

Comment: @PeterGrill, I tested the 2nd version on a freebsd 10.0 VM and it works.  should work on a mac too.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

- extract the year/month/day values into a shell variable,
- create a temporary file
- use the [`touch`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/touch.html) command (adding 0s for hour/minute/second) to set the modification date for the temporary file

Because your question is about `bash`, you likely are using Linux.  The [`test`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) program used in Linux (part of [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/)) has extensions for timestamp comparison (`-nt` and `-ot`) not found in [POSIX `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html).

POSIX comments about this in the rationale for `test`:

> Some additional primaries newly invented or from the KornShell appeared in an early proposal as part of the conditional command (`[[]]`): s1 > s2, s1 < s2, str = pattern, str != pattern, f1 -nt f2, f1 -ot f2, and f1 -ef f2. They were not carried forward into the test utility when the conditional command was removed from the shell because they have not been included in the test utility built into historical implementations of the sh utility.

Using that extension, you could then

- create another temporary file with the date you want to compare against
- use the `-nt` operator in `test` to make the comparison you asked for.

Here is an example.  A clarification by OP mentioned the platform, so one could use `stat` as an alternative to temporary files (compare [OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) and [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat)):

```
#!/bin/bash
# inspect each file...

with_tempfile() {
    echo "** with temporary file $name"
    test=$MYTEMP/$name
    touch -t $date $test
    [ $name -nt $test ] && echo "...newer"
}

# alternatively (and this is system-dependent)
with_stat() {
    echo "** with stat command $name"
    stat=$(stat -t "%Y%m%d%H%M" -f "%Sm" $name)
    [ $stat -gt $date ] && echo "...newer"
}

MYTEMP=$(mktemp -d /var/tmp/isnewer.XXXXXX)
trap "rm -rf $MYTEMP" EXIT
for name in file-name-[0-9][0-9]*.txt
do
    if [ -f "$name" ];
    then
            date=${name%%.txt}
            date=${date/file-name-}
            date=${date//-/}2359
            with_tempfile $name
            with_stat $name
    fi
done
```

Comment: When creating temporary files, it is standard practice to remove overlooked files with a `trap` command.

Comment: I am on MacOS 10.9.5.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Temporary files aren't as elegant as some possible approaches relying on additional extensions, but I'll provide a short sample script, for consistency.

Answer (score 4):

Using bash and `stat` and `expr` to get the dates as numbers and comparing them:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file
do  moddate=$(stat -f %m -t %F "$file") # MacOS stat
    moddate=${moddate//-/} # 20151026
    if filedate=$(expr "$file" : '.*-\([0-9]*\).txt')
    then  if [ $moddate -gt $filedate ]
          then echo "$file: modified $moddate"
          fi
    fi
done
```

---

This was my earlier Linux-specific answer.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file
do  moddate=$(stat -c %y "$file")
    moddate=${moddate%% *} # 2015-10-26
    moddate=${moddate//-/} # 20151026
    if [[ "$file" =~ ([0-9]{8}).txt$ ]]
    then  if [[ $moddate > ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ]]
          then echo "$file: modified $moddate"
          fi
    fi
done
```

The bash `=~` regexp operator captures the 8 digits of the filename
into bash array BASH_REMATCH. `[[ ]]` compares the strings, though
you simply compare them as numbers instead in `[ -gt ]`.

Comment: MacOS 10.9.5 does not seem to have the `-c` option to `stat`.

Comment: My bad. The equivalent seems to be `stat -f %m -t %F "$file"`. Sorry, I can't test it.

Comment: With the change in the `stat` as per your comment, things seem to execute but no output for all test cases.  But, what is the `"$file" =~ ([0-9]{8}).txt$` doing?

Comment: It looks for the 8 digits followed by `.txt` at the end of the filename. The parentheses `()` captures the 8 digits part, and you can find it in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`.

Comment: If your bash doesnt work with `if [[=~]]` you can try the basic `if filedate=$(expr "$file" : '.*-\([0-9]*\).txt')` and then replace `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` by `$filedate`.

Answer (score 1):

Another `zsh` approach:

```
zmodload zsh/stat # best in ~/.zshrc or
zmodload -F zsh/stat +b:zstat # to avoid overriding an eventual
                              # system stat command.
setopt extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc

ls -ld -- **/*[0-9](#c8)*(De@'zstat -F %Y%m%d -A m +mtime $REPLY &&
  [[ ${(SM)${REPLY:t}#[0-9](#c8)} != $m ]]'@)
```

Would report the files that have something that looks like a timestamp in their name but which does not correspond to their last modification time.

`zsh` has a plethora of operators like that to manipulate globs and variables. It's very handy to get  any job done quickly (and generally reliably) but it's quite hard to get your head around them all and it often produces what we usually call *write-only* code (euphemism for illegible code, though also implies that you don't need to read it as you write it for a single usage at the command prompt)

A quick run through:

- `**/pattern(qualifier)`: recursive glob with glob qualifier.
- `[0-9](#c8)` matches 8 digits. That's the zsh extendedglob equivalent of `ksh`'s `{8}([0-9])`.
- `D`: include hidden files
- `e@...@`: the *eval* glob qualifier to run some text to further qualify files. File path passed in `$REPLY`
- `zstat...` retrieve the mtime formatted as YYYYMMDD in the `$m` array.
- `${REPLY:t}`: expands to the **t**tail (the basename) of the file.
- `${(SM)something#pattern}`. Extract the part matching *pattern* from *something*. Those `S` (**S**ubstring search) and `M` (expand to **M**atched portion) are called *parameter expansion flags*.